# SSO using drupal CAS module from drupal on one system to sample java webapp on another system(having different ip) not happening

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, cas, jasig, phpcas

I want to achieve SSO for the two system one running on php(drupal) in one system and another running on java on onother server. To achieve this I used the JASIG's CAS (Central authentication service) open source software. I installed JASIG CAS server on the machine where my drupal installation is situated. I also configured the JDBC backend support of CAS server and created an user authentication database on the same machine where drupal is installed. Then I installed the drupal CAS module in my drupal installation. Then on the same machine where drupal is installed I installed a sample java web application on the tomcat server (JASIG CAS is also installed on the same tomcat server on the same drupal machine). In the sample java web application I have configured the web.xml file to include the CAS java client filters as stated in JASIG's website. Then I provided the link of sample java application in the home page of my drupal installation. When I am logging into the drupal site it is getting logged in through CAS server authentication and authenticating the user by consulting CAS server user authentication database. After logging in when I am clicking on the sample java application link on the home page it is not asking me to log in again and opening the sample java application page thus providing SSO.
     Now when I configured the same sample java application on different machine (having different i.p) and providing the link of the java application of different machine on my drupal home page SSO is not happening and clicking on the link of the java application is redirecting me to the CAS login page even when I am logged in to the drupal installation through CAS. Both the machines are connected through LAN. Please help me in solving the issue. If you need more specific details please let me know. Thanks in advance**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

if you use ssl with self-signed certification,you should import the certification into all cas-client jvm ,like the below:

`keytool -import -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts -file server.crt -alias jetty`

the default password is

> changeit